# How to mock reactive repository which returns Observable

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

So i have repository, which provides the Observable to the client. Is there a way i can mock this repository, so i don't need to send location from my emulator or using the real device to gain some Location?

Here is how the interface looks like:

```
interface RxLocationRepository {

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
fun onLocationUpdate(): Observable<Location>

fun stopLocationUpdates()
}
```

In my client side i use this like this:

```
class LocationManager(
    val rxLocationRepository: RxLocationRepository){

private fun appendGeoEvent(location: Location) {
    val locationGeoEvent = LocationGeoEvent(
            accuracy = location.accuracy.toDouble(),
            latitude = location.latitude,
            longitude = location.longitude,
            timestampGeoEvent = location.time
    )
    processGeoEvent(locationGeoEvent)
}

compositeDisposable.add(rxLocationRepository.onLocationUpdate()
            .subscribe(Consumer { location ->
                appendGeoEvent(location)
            }))
 ....
```

So i sending this obtained location to my appendGeoEvent method.

I can use for example Mockito, but i don't know how to mock this repository so i can use the fake locations.
Also, i want to use Kotlin.

Comment: How do you use the dependency to `RxLocationRepository`?

Comment: @tynn I updated my question, not sure what do you mean. I use Dagger to inject my repository to the client

Comment: Ah, ok. So i need to create another module, which will be only in my test package? So in Dagger i must not provide this Repository through constructor and just add this manually in test or how to achive this with dagger? ESala answer seems legit after this

Comment: @okset I don't think you need another Dagger module for this. Besides, your `LocationManager` does not use the repository, so you could remove it from the constructor. Anyways, you need to think about what you are really testing. If you are testing the `LocationManager.appendGeoEvent(...)` method, then you don't even need a repository mock, just create a test location like in my answer and use it to call the method. Hope this helps ;)

Comment: It actually use this repository, i;ve just removed the "append" function, so i only depend on location delivered from the repository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to setup different Dagger module, which just provide me implementation of this repository - it returns different Observable stream.

I set it up like this.

```
@Module
abstract class StubLocationRepositoryModule {

@Binds
internal abstract fun bindsRxLocationRepository(stubRxLocationRepository: StubRxLocationRepository) : RxLocationRepository
}
```

I was just using this in my androidTest package in component.

So my implementation was like this:

just an example:

```
class StubRxLocationRepository @Inject constructor(val stubLocationParameterName: String) : RxLocationRepository {

val location = Location("test").apply {
    latitude = 1.234
    longitude = 5.678
    accuracy = 20f
    time = Date().time
}

override fun onLocationUpdate(): Observable<Location> {
    Log.v("StubLocationRepository", "CHOSEN PARAMETER: $stubLocationParameterName")


    return when (stubLocationParameterName) {
        "highFreq" -> Observable.interval(50, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .flatMap(
                        {
                            Observable.just(location)
                        }
                )
                .doOnNext{ t: Location -> Log.v("onLocationUpdate", t.toString()) }
        else -> Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .flatMap(
                        {
                            Observable.just(location)
                        }
                )
                .doOnNext{ t: Location -> Log.v("onLocationUpdate", t.toString()) }
    }
}

override fun stopLocationUpdates() {
    Log.v("StubLocationRepository", "stopLocationUpdates")
}
}
```

So in my Dagger Component builder i expose a method which will provide me some parameter in which i will depend in the StubRxLocation implementation - it will return me some stream i need for specific test case.

So the component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(StubLocationRepositoryModule::class, 
LocationTestInstrumentalModule::class, StubRssiRepositoryModule::class))
interface LocationTestInstrumentalComponent{
fun locationClient(): LocationClient


@Component.Builder
interface Builder {
    @BindsInstance
    fun context(context: Context): Builder
    @BindsInstance
    fun stubLocationRepositoryParameter(stubLocationRepositoryParameter: String): Builder
    fun build(): LocationTestInstrumentalComponent
}

}
```

So in every test i can bring the mocked repository it like this, which will be ready form me to use for that test case:

```
@Test
fun someTest(){
       val component = DaggerLocationTestInstrumentalComponent.builder().stubLocationRepositoryParameter("highFreq").context(InstrumentationRegistry.getContext()).build()

val client = component.locationClient()
//i can expose some other methods, not only this 'locationClient' in this Component to return me some classes, like this RxLocationRepository(which will behave as i want) and others
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If using Mockito, you could do something like this:

```
import android.location.Location
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.mockito.Mockito
import org.mockito.Mockito.`when`
import org.mockito.Mockito.mock
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner
import java.util.*

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class LocationsTest{

    @Test
    fun should_return_one_location() {
        val location = Location("test").apply {
            latitude = 1.234
            longitude = 5.678
            // ...
        }
        val mockRepository = mock(RxLocationRepository::class.java)
        `when`(mockRepository.onLocationUpdate()).thenReturn(Observable.just(location))
        // use the mock
    }

}
```

I am using: `testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.11.0"`

Comment: What mockito i need for gradle, to use it like this? I am using testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.19" and this is not recognized

Comment: @okset I have updated the answer with a full example. What do you mean not recognized? try to re-build the project.

Comment: Ok, i found the answer i was using it in androidTest, not test. So:     // required if you want to use Mockito for unit tests
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.22'
    // required if you want to use Mockito for Android tests
    androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.7.22'

Comment: @okset if the answer worked, could you consider accepting it?

Comment: The answer would work if i want to use that repository in the test(the same instance), but the repository was actually implemented and closed in different class, provided with Dagger. So i cannot mock it like this, however i just set up new Dagger module which will provide me this mock implementation only for test, in different test project module. So i guess your answer will work of course, if you want to test something which is not provided with Dagger, because my repository is embedded and cannot mock it like this in test